# Creating a new directory in the photo library of iPhone using PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, cordova, camera, directory, photo

I am currently developing an mobile app using the PhoneGap framework. I am just wondering if there is any PhoneGap APIs or plugins that will allow us to create a new directory inside the iPhone's photo library. So every time when a user is using my app to capture a picture, I can have it saved into that directory.

Comment: please check this one https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/6n7jGIey9hA

Comment: Have you done some research on the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my little knowledge, currently you cant create a new directory inside the iPhone's photo library using phoneGap

However you can save an image in to iPhone's photo library.

See the below code

```
<a href="#" onclick="runImageTest('/www/underboob.png');">save image</a> 

function runImageTest(img) 
{ 
   PhoneGap.exec("ImageHelper.saveToUserLibrary",img); 
}
```

Please see the discussions [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/6n7jGIey9hA)